# How to parse data and put it in a Spark SQL table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a log file that I would like to analyze using Spark SQL. The format of the log file is like this:

```
71.19.157.174 - - [24/Sep/2014:22:26:12 +0000] "GET /error HTTP/1.1" 404 505 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
```

I have a regular expression pattern that I can use to parse the data:

```
Pattern.compile("""^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] \"(\S+) (\S+) (\S+)\" (\d{3}) (\d+)""")
```

Additionally, I've also created the case class:

```
case class LogSchema(ip: String, client: String, userid: String, date: String, method: String, endpoint: String, protocol: String, response: String, contentsize: String)
```

However, I'm unable to convert this into a table on which I can run spark sql queries.

How can I use the regex pattern to parse the data and put it in a table?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's the issue?

Comment: can you update in the question with what the fields in data match with case class fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you have your log file in `/home/user/logs/log.txt`, then you can use the following logic to get the `table`/`dataframe` from the log file.

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("/home/user/logs/log.txt")
val pattern = Pattern.compile("""^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([\w:/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})\] \"(\S+) (\S+) (\S+)\" (\d{3}) (\d+)""")
val df = rdd.map(line => pattern.matcher(line)).map(elem => {
  elem.find
  LogSchema(elem.group(1), elem.group(2), elem.group(3), elem.group(4), elem.group(5), elem.group(6), elem.group(7), elem.group(8), elem.group(9))
}).toDF()
df.show(false)
```

You should have following `dataframe`

```
+-------------+------+------+--------------------------+------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
|ip           |client|userid|date                      |method|endpoint|protocol|response|contentsize|
+-------------+------+------+--------------------------+------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
|71.19.157.174|-     |-     |24/Sep/2014:22:26:12 +0000|GET   |/error  |HTTP/1.1|404     |505        |
+-------------+------+------+--------------------------+------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
```

I have used the `case class` you've provided.

```
case class LogSchema(ip: String, client: String, userid: String, date: String, method: String, endpoint: String, protocol: String, response: String, contentsize: String)
```